# Reading all certificates from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate

I have a problem with reading certificates. I have a **web service** that has to get a certificate **serial number**  using part of the subject. Everything works fine if I'm doing it from a form but when I try it from a web service it seems that it cannot find any certificate. I'm using this code to read all of the the certificates:

```
                        X509Store store = new X509Store();

                        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);                    
if (args.Parameters["CertificateName"].ToString() != "")
                    {

                        foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
                        {
                            if (mCert.Subject.Contains("OU=" + args.Parameters["CertificateName"].ToString()))
                            {
                                SerialNum = mCert.SerialNumber;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (SerialNum == String.Empty)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Certificate not found with name: " + args.Parameters["CertificateName"].ToString() + " ;" + " OU=" + args.Parameters["CertificateName"]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
                        {
                            if (mCert.Subject.Contains("OU=Eua"))
                            {
                                SerialNum = mCert.SerialNumber;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (SerialNum == String.Empty)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Haven't found default certificate ;");
                        }

                    }
store=null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [parameterless constructor for X509Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h18w8fws(v=vs.110).aspx) which according to the documentation will open the cert store for the current user.  Well, the current user for your forms application is probably not the same as the current user for your web application, which most likely runs within an AppDomain configured to use a service account.  So that means the web application won't be able to find it.

To fix this, you have two options

### Option 1

First store your certificate in the machine store (not the user store).  Then, in your code, open the store using [a different constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b814c6tk(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you specify the [store location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation(v=vs.110).aspx), and specify that you want the machine store.  Like this:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.MachineStore);
```

### Option 2

Maintain two copies of the certificate.  Follow these steps:

1. Export the certificate from your current user's cert store
2. Start certificate manager using "RunAs" to impersonate the service account for the app domain, e.g. `runas /user:MyDomain\MyServiceAccount "cmd /c start /B certmgr.msc"`.  When prompted make sure you tell it you want to work with the current user's cert store, not the machine store.
3. Import the certificate there
4. Open the cert up and make sure its chain of trust is intact; if any intermediate or root certs are missing, you may have to import those as well.
5. Remember when this cert expires, you will have to replace both copies.